# What is the difference between the account of the crucifixion, death and burial of Christ in the book of Mathew, Mark, Luke and John

Tags: john

What is the difference between the account of the crucifixion, death and burial of Christ in  the book of Mathew, Mark, Luke and John

Comment: he seeming conflict is so many details are left out. The differing accounts show differing original sources. – Perry Webb 29 mins ago

Comment: Your question is very broad and without any scripture citation, it is likely to get close for not adhering to site guidelines.

Comment: Most of the conflicts are in fact not between the Gospel accounts themselves, but between the accounts and later traditions. ¶ You might want to look at my [Crucifixion/Resurrection Synoptic Time Table](https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Tables/crucifixion-resurrection/). ¶ What are the specific details that you find troublesome?

Answer (score 4):

Differences/Commonalities in the Gospel accounts of Crucifixion/Death/Burial/Resurrection of Christ?

**Answer**: The following information can be found [here](https://www.westmont.edu/%7Efisk/Articles/Passion-Gospels%20Compared.pdf) as a downloadable PDF by B.N. Fisk. It seems relatively comprehensive:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At these links is the answer to you question with great detail.

https://www.kootenaichurch.org/articles-pdf/resurrection/Harmonizing-The-Resurrection-Accounts-Part-1.pdf

https://www.kootenaichurch.org/articles-pdf/resurrection/Harmonizing-The-Resurrection-Accounts-Part-2.pdf

Jim Osman's conclusion to part one

> So it is with the gospels. We have four
> independent, eyewitness accounts of the same event.
> These accounts provide complementary, but not
> contradictory, information.

> There are no contradictions between the gospel
> accounts of the resurrection. There are differences,
> even very intriguing differences, but there are no
> necessary contradictions. There are statements that
> may appear contradictory, but when we examine
> them, accounting for the perspective of the author, we
> find that there are ways of understanding the events
> that do not require us to conclude that one or any of
> the gospel writers had it wrong.

> When we put these accounts together we get a
> complete picture not a contradictory picture.

> In part two, I will reconstruct the events of that first
> Easter morning in a way that accounts for all the
> details. We will see that a harmonization of these
> accounts is anything but impossible.

> Without Wax -

Answer (score 0):

There are considerable differences around the crucifixion, too many to mention.  I have mentioned d some clear and obvious / well know points.  To examine this topic fully would be too wide, but the internet has so much from all different points of view.
One must also decide are the gospels God inspired or merely men, arguably unknown men who have written accounts and how should we see the contradictions.

***BUILD UP TO THE CRUCIFIXION***

***Are there any witnesses***

Then you have a clear statement from;
Mark 14:50
50 And they all forsook him, and fled. – how can there be witnesses if they ‘fled’

Enoch Pawl book ‘Development of the Gospels’ says that the crucifixion was not mentioned in the original Gospels.  He retranslated the Greek copy of Mathew’s
Gospel; and he found that some passages were repeated in the
Gospel, which means it was re-written later.

***Only Luke mentions the below***
Luke 23:33-34 (RSV)
34 And Jesus said, “Father, forgive them; for they know not what they do.”[a] And they cast lots to divide his garments.

Noticing the destruction that happened to Jerusalem twice, in year 70 C.E and 135 C.E, it was certain that God did not forgive them”.

***Did the Chief priest come to arrest Jesus***

Matthew said, "And a large mob armed with swords and clubs was with him. They had been ***sent by the chief priests*** and the nation's leaders."
(Matthew 26:47)

"And straightway, while he yet spake, cometh Judas, one of the twelve, and with him a multitude with swords and staves, ***from the chief priests*** and the scribes and the elders. (Mark 14:43)

"So he went to the garden with some Roman soldiers and temple police, who had been ***sent by the chief priests*** and the Pharisees." (John 18:3)

***"Jesus spoke to the chief priests***, the temple police, and the
leaders who had come to arrest him." (Luke 22/52)

***Prosecution***

***"At daybreak*** the nation's leaders, the chief priests, and the teachers of the Law of Moses got together and brought Jesus before their council. They said, "Tell us! Are you the Messiah?" (Luke 22/66-67).

The other 3 say the prosecution was at night.

***How many times did the cock crow***

"Before the cock crow twice, thou shalt deny me thrice." (Mark 14:72)

different to Luke and the others

"Before the cock crow this day thou shalt deny me thrice." (Luke 22/61)

***When did the maid recognize Peter for the first time***

"Then saith the damsel that kept the door unto Peter, Art not thou also one of this man's disciples?" (John 18:17) –

recognised at the gate – yet the others say Peter was sat in the midst of them, see (Luke 22:55-56, Matthew 26:69, Mark 14:66)

***which maid***

"And the ***maid saw him***, and began again to say to them that stood by, This is one of them." (Mark 14/69) – same maid

"And when he was gone out into the porch, another maid saw him, and said unto them that were there, This man also was with Jesus of Nazareth." Matthew 26:71

***Barabbas***

"Now Barabbas was a robber" John 18:40

"But ye denied the Holy and Righteous One, and asked for a murderer to be granted unto you." Acts 3:14 – see also Luke 23:19 & Mark 15:7

***Who carried the cross, Jesus or Simon***

Simon - Mark 15:20-22, Matthew 27:32, Luke 23:26

Jesus - John 19:17

***The story of Judah’s death***

2 different stories - Matthew 27:2-7 & Acts 1:16-20

***other two crucified men about Jesus***

"And the robbers also that were crucified with him cast upon him the same reproach." Matthew 27:44, same in Mark 15:32

Yet Luke 23:39-43

"And one of the malefactors that were hanged railed on him, saying, Art not thou the Christ? Save thyself and us. But the other answered, and rebuking him said, Dost thou not even fear God…And he said unto him, Verily I say unto thee, Today shalt thou be with me in Paradise."

***Last words***

“Jesus
cried with a loud voice, saying, Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani? That is, My God, my God, why hast thou forsaken me?” then he died. Matthew 27:46-50 & Mark 15:34-37).

OR

"And Jesus gave a loud cry and said, Father, into your hands I give my spirit: and when he had said this, he gave up his spirit." (Luke 23:46).

OR

"When Jesus therefore had received the vinegar, he said, It is finished: and he bowed his head, and gave up his spirit." John 19:30.

***Veil of the temple rent***

"And Jesus uttered a loud voice, and gave up his spirit. And the veil of the temple was rent in two from the top to the bottom." Mark 15:37-38 (after his spirit)

OR

And it was now about the sixth hour, and a darkness came over the whole land until the ninth hour, the sun's light failing: and the veil of the temple was rent in the midst. And Jesus, crying with a loud voice, said, Father, into thy hands I commend my spirit: and having said this, he gave up his spirit." Luke 23:44-46
(before his spirit)

***when and who came to the Tomb***
some has already been mentioned, add the following:

Matthew 28:1-4 After the Sabbath, at dawn on the first day of the week, Mary Magdalene and the other Mary went to look at the tomb. 2 There was a violent earthquake, for an angel of the Lord came down from heaven and, going to the tomb, rolled back the stone and sat on it. 3 His appearance was like lightning, and his clothes were white as snow. 4 The guards were so afraid of him that they shook and became like dead men. 9 Suddenly Jesus met them. “Greetings,” he said. They came to him, clasped his feet and worshiped him.

OR

John 20:1-2
20 Early on the first day of the week, while it was still dark, Mary Magdalene went to the tomb and saw that the ***stone had been removed*** from the entrance. 2 So she came ***running to Simon Peter*** and the other disciple, the one Jesus loved, and said, “They have taken the Lord out of the tomb, and we don’t know where they have put him!”

***On the basis that Jesus became a spirit or is the Holy Spirit why did an Angel need to move the Tomb stone based on below;***

John 20: 19-20 & 26-27 19 Then, the same day at evening, being the first day of the week, when the **doors were shut** where the disciples were assembled, for fear of the Jews, Jesus came and stood in the midst, and said to them, “Peace be with you.” 20 When He had said this, He showed them His hands and His side. Then the disciples were glad when they saw the Lord.

26 A week later his disciples were in the house again, and Thomas was with them. Though the doors were locked, Jesus came and stood among them and said, “Peace be with you!” 27 Then he said to Thomas, “Put your finger here; see my hands. Reach out your hand and put it into my side. Stop doubting and believe.”

*** What did the female visitors see***

Mark - visitors saw a young man sitting at the right side of the tomb, wearing a white garment. Mark 5:16
Matthew - an angel descended from heaven Matthew 28:2
Luke - two men in bright clothes Luke 24:4
John - two angels in white clothes. One sat near the head, and the other near the legs John 20:12

***Magdalene told by Jesus or the Angel***

John 20:13 -16 – meet Jesus thought he was a gardener

OR

Matthew 28:5-10 – the angel told her about Jesus and where he was laying

***Did the women hide the news, or did they reveal it***

"And they said nothing to any one; for they were afraid." Mark 16:8

"And returned from the tomb, and told all these things to the eleven, and to all the rest." Luke 24:9

***To whom did Jesus appear the first time***

Mark and John, Jesus first appeared to Mary Magdalene. Mark 16:9, John 20:14

Matthew added another Mary - Matthew 28:9

***How many times did Jesus appear and where***

John 26:19- 20 – 3 times

Matthew 28:16, Mark 16:14 (Galilee), Luke 24:33-36 (Jerusalem) – once only

***Passover Festival***

They had the Passover festival with Jesus MARK 14:16-18, MATTHEW 26:19-21, LUKE 22:13-15

YET

It was ***just before the Passover Festival.*** Jesus knew that the hour
had come for him to leave this world and go to the Father. Having
loved his own who were in the world, he loved them to the end.
The evening meal was in progress... [John 13:1-2]

Now it was the day of Preparation of the Passover. It was about
the sixth hour. He said to the Jews, “Behold your King!” They cried
out, “Away with him, away with him, crucify him!” Pilate said to
them, “Shall I crucify your King?” The chief priests answered, “We
have no king but Caesar.” [John 19:14-15]

***How long did Jesus stay on earth before his ascending***

ascended to heaven on the day of the resurrection. (See: Matthew 28:8 -20, Mark 16: 9-19, Luke 24:1-53)

Acts says 40 days

***Few general points***

“Who in the days of his flesh, having offered up prayers and supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to ***save him from death***,and having been heard for his godly fear." (Hebrews 5:7),

Father, I thank thee that thou heardest me. And I knew that thou hearest me always." (John 11:41-42).

Psalm 20:6 6Now I know that the LORD saves His anointed; He answers him from His holy heaven with the saving power of His right hand.

“O you who lift me up from the gates of death” (Psalms 9:13)

"When evil-doers came upon me to eat up my flesh, Even mine adversaries and my foes, they stumbled and fell… For in the day of trouble he will keep me secretly in his pavilion: In the covert of his tabernacle will he hide me." (Psalms 27:2-5)

Psalm 21:2 - You have given him his heart’s desire, And have not withheld the request of his lips. Selah

Psalms 34:20 He protects all his bones; not one of them will be broken

PSALM 91:10-15 10 no harm will overtake you, no disaster will come near your tent.11 For he will command his angels concerning you to guard you in all your ways; 12 they will lift you up in their hands, so that you will not strike your foot against a stone. 13 You will tread on the lion and the cobra; you will trample the great lion and the serpent. 14 “Because he loves me,” says the LORD, “I will rescue him; I will protect him, for he acknowledges my name. 15 He will call on me, and I will answer him;
I will be with him in trouble, I will deliver him and honor him.

Luke 24:39 - "Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have".

Jonah (prayed and was alive) - 7 When my life was ***fainting away,*** I remembered the Lord, and my prayer came to you, into your holy temple.

Deuteronomy 21:22-23 22 If someone guilty of a capital offense is put to death and their body is exposed on a pole, 23 you must not leave the body hanging on the pole overnight. Be sure to bury it that same day, because anyone who is hung on a pole is under God’s curse. You must not desecrate the land the Lord your God is giving you as an inheritance.